# Getting Windows 7 from MSDN

Tags: windows-7

I have a full MSDN subscription.

I see that the version of Windows 7 x86 English dates back from 08/24/2009.

What does that mean? Is it the full retail final version still?

They also have a "N" version from 10/22/2009, but I understand this is for Europe.

Comment: The "N" version is for Korea, dropping, IIRC, media player (the "E" version for Europe was abandoned).

Comment: This week I received Windows 7 and Server 2008 R2 DVDs for MSDN, so it might be you won't need a download unless your timeline is critical.

Comment: N is no media player (for Europe - it's a different anti-trust settlement from the E version).  K is a version for Korea which has links to download third-party media players and instant messengers.  KN is a combination of both, ie no media player, and links to non-Microsoft media players / IM clients.  Some businesses prefer installing the N version so users can't play CDs at their desks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows 7 has been completed since the beginning of August, so, yes, your "Windows 7 x86 English from 08/24/2009" is the full final retail version.

edit: it was actually finished on 22 July, and was first available on MSDN on 6 August

Answer (score 4):

Correct. I've been running RTM since August--it's the same version that has just been released to the public.

Also note that if you use IE to download it, it uses the MS downloader. If you use Firefox, it just gives you the file directly. As much as I don't like the MS downloader, for a 3-4gb file, I think it's worth it.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, the MSDN, TechNet, and Partner Program releases are the same as the Retail versions. As you stated, they have been available to MSDN and TechNet subscribers, as well as Partner Program members (at the Certified or Gold Certified levels only) since August.

N is for Europe

K and KN are for South Korea